# Lord Windgrace; Resolving the First Loyalty Ability

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Lord Windgrace](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=450644)'s first ability reads:

> +2: Discard a card, then draw a card. If a land card is discarded this way, draw an additional card.

If a land is discarded with this ability, is the order of events with this to **draw**, **discard**, then **draw** again because it doesn't specify to draw an additional card—or draw two cards—*"instead?"*

The confused other approach would be seeing the ability as reading to **draw**, **draw**, **discard**; which I believe is the way I initially interpreted it.

I believe I recognize that a replacement effect is **not** in place here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Neither of your interpretations are correct. The order of events is *discard*, *draw*, [*draw*].** Look at the way the ability is ordered "+2: Discard a card, then [...]" The very first thing you do while resolving this ability is discard a card, then you draw either one or two cards. There is no replacement effect involved, and the first draw is unconditional. This means that even if you fail to discard a card (no cards in hand) you will draw that first card, but the discard definitely happens first if possible.

Comment: Y'know, somehow I kept misreading the card every time I was trying to understand and acknowledge the ability, and even in asking the question I re-read it many, many times over believing I had it all correct before posting it. My confusion doesn't make sense here and the question doesn't make sense to be asked in the first place. My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, there is no replacement effect here.  Just follow the instructions as written in the order written.  So:

1. Discard a card.  Any card you want, but be aware your choice has consequences.
2. Draw a card.  Unconditional, you just do it.
3. If you discarded a land card in step 1, you draw another card.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Discard a land card, and draw two cards.
2. Discard a non-land card, and draw one card.

You alert your opponent as to which option you've picked, by what you are discarding.

Answer (score 0):

The rulings on gatherer may help clarify:

> If you have no cards in hand as Lord Windgrace’s first ability
> resolves, you’ll discard nothing **then** you’ll draw one card.

(emphasis mine). You discard a card before drawing any cards.